# How to get back a clean git repository?

Tags: linux, git, github, gitlab, git-bash

I have got a github repo from Customer side .
 After that I could see the changes in the Github.
 But found that given old, faulty, junk tree.
I have successfully push the initial code base using these commands.

```
git clone git@github.com:ABC/ABCSoft.git
cp -rv /home/LifeStyle .
git add --all
git commit -m "Initial codebase v1.0.0"
git log
git push origin master
```

**How to undo all and get a clean repo?**

So that I can push the actual fresh tree without having the last commit log or traces.

*There is no control from my side to delete that repo and create once again.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Completely reset do this steps:

Delete the .git directory locally.

Recreate the git repostory:

```
$ cd (project-directory)
$ git init
$ (add some files)
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'Initial commit'
```

Push to remote server, overwriting.
Remember you're going to mess everyone else up doing this … you better be the only client.

```
$ git remote add origin <url>
$ git push --force --set-upstream origin master
```

Comment: This is also a good example of why "--force" / "-f" should not be used lightly.

Answer (score 1):

```
git log
git reset --hard <tag/branch/commit id>
```

P.S : git `reset` without `--hard` only reset the commit history. Where as with `--hard` option the files in working tree are also reset.